# how to avoid whitespace on right side if columns are less in Ag grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

The answer might be sizeTofit .
But When I have to resize the column then that whitespace is coming on the right side of the grid.

So I need to do the last column of the grid to occupy the grid fully if columns are less (Or if I remove come column)otherwise it will take the column width provided by the property to Ag grid

This is the image I am getting now

[image: This is the image I am getting now]

like this I want

[image: like this I want]

Answer (score 1):

if size of it is not what you want then you can write a function and do the calculations manually.

set the width of columns and at the end set new column defs to your ag grid;

```
var tableWidth = sth;
var totalWidth = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<columnDefs.length; i++) {
    totalWidth += columnDefs[i].width;
    if((i == columnDefs.length - 1) && (totalWidth < tableWidth)) {
        columnDefs[i] += tableWidth - totalWidth;
    }
}
api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

Comment: ya it is true what you are saying but when I used to resize the column then same whitespace problem will some.

Comment: Is there any way to do the last column to the fit to the grid dynamically means.If I remove some column or I rearrange the columns then it is dymanically set the last dynamically set to the remaining space of the grid.

Comment: I'm not sure if ag-grid has such a capability. but after resizing an event rises. you can call your function whenever the gird needs to be fit.

Comment: ya if I am trying to increase the width of the last column. so it is not possible dynamically.Because I dont know how much I should incrrease.